# Template ReadProcessMemory with dereferencing

Tags: c++, windows, templates

So I have a template function using `ReadProcessMemory` to read my game from an external program for debugging.

This is the function:

```
template<typename T>
T read(DWORD addy)
{
    T buffer;
    ReadProcessMemory(targetProcess, (LPVOID)addy, &buffer, sizeof(T), NULL);
    assert(buffer != NULL);
    return buffer;
}
```

Now I would like to read a multi-level pointer with several dereferences such as this one:

```
*(*(game.exe+0x12345)+0x50)+0x70
```

And my goal is to be able to do that with my template function:

```
float data = read<float>(((game.exe+0x12345)+0x50)+0x70);
```

Without the dereferences and even if *possible* without the parenthesis.

I was thinking of using a **parameter pack** for my template, but I'm not sure if it's optimal in my case.

such as this:

```
template<typename T>
T retVal(T val){
   return *val;
} 


template<typename T, typename ...LvlsType>
T read(DWORD addy, LvlsType... levels){
    T buffer;
    ReadProcessMemory(targetProcess, (LPVOID)addy, &buffer, sizeof(T), NULL);
    assert(buffer != NULL);
    return retVal(...levels);
}
```

Would that be correct in this case?

Otherwise would you guys have any advices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the point of `assert(buffer != NULL);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DWORD addy` should be `DWORD_PTR addy`, or even `void* addy`.

And the `assert()` is useless. You need to check the return value of `ReadProcessMemory()` instead.

In any case, you can't avoid reading multiple values.  The game has multiple pointers, you need to read them individually and follow the addresses, just like the game does. So, your attempt to use `read<float>(((game.exe+0x12345)+0x50)+0x70);` will not work.

You need to first read a pointer value located at address `game.exe+0x12345`.  Then you need to add `0x50` to that value and read a pointer value located at that address.  Then add `0x70` to that value and read a `float` located at that address.

You can try something more like this:

```
template<typename T>
T read(DWORD_PTR addy)
{
    T buffer;
    if (!ReadProcessMemory(targetProcess, (LPVOID)addy, &buffer, sizeof(T), NULL))
        throw ...;
    return buffer;
}

template<typename T, typename... OffsetTypes>
T read(DWORD_PTR addy, DWORD offset, OffsetTypes... offsets)
{
    DWORD ptr = read<DWORD>(addy);
    return read<T>(ptr + offset, offsets...);
}

...

DWORD_PTR baseAddr = ...; // base address of game.exe process
float data = read<float>(baseAddr+0x12345, 0x50, 0x70);
```

The use of `DWORD ptr` in the variadic version of `read()` assumes `game.exe` is a 32bit EXE.  If it is a 64bit EXE instead, change `DWORD ptr` to `DWORD64 ptr`, and make sure your code is compiled for 64bit so that `DWORD_PTR addy` will be `DWORD64` and can reach all possible 64bit addresses.

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/xtO1TU)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helpful! I’ll try your version tomorrow :D